# getting an ad based on a person's interest list in Flutter is possible

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, admob

I use FireBase and I have an Admob account. I want to get ads based on the list of interests of the user

I have shown ads inside the applications, but ads that I do not want come, so I set up a list of interests in order to display ads according to them